# The use of OpenArgs or stLinkCriteria

Tags: openargs

Got a concept question.  On opening a form, is it better to use stLinkCriteria or OpenArgs??  If there is a difference, when should one be preferred over the other?

Thanx
Bill

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you're doing.

stLinkCriteria is good for opening a new form.

OpenArgs is the only way I know of to send variables to a newly opened form since the OnLoad event of the form can process the variables sent via OpenArgs.